# how to make my code (AsyncTask) cleaner?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I need to build an android app for my final year project, (i am new to android development). Is there any idea to minimize the code or maybe separate into different classes.

I want to make my main activity shorter and cleaner for maintenance, and  preferably if it can be coded using MVC architecture.  There will be more UI components added later. 
Thank you for ur attention.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button find_button;
    EditText user_origin;
    EditText user_destination;
    private TextView json_output;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        find_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.find_button);
        json_output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.json_output);
        user_origin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_origin);
        user_destination = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_destination);

        find_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            String origin;
            String new_origin;
            String destination;
            String new_user_destination;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
               origin = user_origin.getText().toString();
               new_origin = origin.replaceAll(" ", "+");
               destination = user_destination.getText().toString();
               new_user_destination = destination.replaceAll(" ", "+");

               String link = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + new_origin + "&destination=" + new_user_destination + "&mode=transit&key=AIzaSyD83XCiGtJyo6Ln8c7yyyrQwmFDFZB_oiU";

                //json_output.setText(link);
                new JSONTask().execute(link);
            }
        });



    }

    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params){
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try{
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null ){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                String final_json = buffer.toString();

                return buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if(reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            json_output.setText("result:" +result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate your `JSONTask` as a simple class,and execute its task,then define an interface in this class to pass some message or data should be handled by other class,and add a parameter type is this interface for constructor and save it as a field.like this:

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    private OnHandleResult mResult;
    private String[] mParams;
    public JSONTask(OnHandleResult onHandleResult,String... params){
        this.mResult = onHandleResult;
        this.mParams = params;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
    //params is empty,get params from this.mParams
    }

     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //json_output.setText("result:" +result);
        this.mResult.handleResult(result);
    }

    public static interface OnHandleResult{
        void handleResult(final String result);
    }
}
```

then let your activity implement interface `onHandleResult`,and hanlde result:set text to textview:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements JSONTask.OnHandleResult{
    void handleResult(final String result){
         json_output.setText("result:" +result);
    }
}
```

and execute task like this:

```
new JSONTask(this,link).execute();
```

Comment: can i also make another class just for UI components?

Comment: you can change the constructor parameter from `OnHandleResult` to `Activity`,then only subclass of Activity can handle data,but you should guarantee your activity implements this interface.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's good practise to have 1 class per file. 
You can make your MainActivity a bit more readable

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button find_button;
EditText user_origin;
EditText user_destination;
private TextView json_output;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    find_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.find_button);
    json_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.json_output);
    user_origin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_origin);
    user_destination = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_destination);

    String link = build_link(user_origin, user_destination);

    MyListener l = new MyListener(link);
    find_button.setOnClickListener(l);
}

private String build_link(EditText user_origin, EditText user_destination) {

    String origin = user_origin.getText().toString();
    String new_origin = origin.replaceAll(" ", "+");
    String destination = user_destination.getText().toString();
    String new_user_destination = destination.replaceAll(" ", "+");

    return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + new_origin + "&destination=" + new_user_destination + "&mode=transit&key=AIzaSyD83XCiGtJyo6Ln8c7yyyrQwmFDFZB_oiU";
}
```

by isolating your listener's implementation:

```
public class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener {

String link;

public MyListener(String link) {

    this.link = link;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    new JSONTask().execute(link);
}
```